# How to rearrange a function y = f[x] into x = g[y]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a differential equation A*dx/dt + B(y-y0) = 0
Where x is a very complicated function of y.

How can I use Mathematica to rearrange y to get a function x in order to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two or three different problems here that you might be asking:

**Option 1: The subject line**

First, if you really do have a function f[x] defined and you want to rearrange it, you would be doing something like this:

```
f[x_]=2+x+x^2;
Solve[y==f[x],x]
```

However, even here you should notice that inverse functions are not necessarily unique. There are two functions given, and the domain of each is only for y>=7/4.

**Option 2: Solving a DE**

Now, the equation you give is a **differential equation**. That is not the same as "rearranging a function y=f[x] into x=g[y]" because there are derivatives involved.

Mathematica has a built-in differential-equation solver:

```
DSolve[a y'[t] + b (y[t] - y0) == 0, y[t], t]
```

That will give you a function (in terms of constants $a,b,y_0$) that is the answer, and it will include the unspecified constant of integration.

Your system seems to refer to two functions, x(t) and y(t). You cannot solve one equation for two variables, so it is impossible to solve this (Mathematica or otherwise) without more information.

**Option 3: Rearranging an expression**

As a third alternative, if you are trying to rearrange this equation *without solving the differential equation*, you can do that:

```
Solve[a x'[t] + b(y[t]-y0)==0,x'[t]]
```

This will give you $x'(t)$ in terms of the other constants and the function $y(t)$, but in order to integrate this (i.e. to solve the differential equation) you will need to know more about y[t].